# Java programs :- Check its mobile number or not in java?

Tags: java

**Interview Program**

**Preparing for Interview @ Beginners Level**

I am getting an error while running below code

```
package InterviewPrograms;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Utility
{
    static boolean numberOrNot(String input)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
public class CheckMobileNumber 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value to check number or not and its indian mobile number or not");
        String value = input.next();
        if(Utility.numberOrNot(value))
        {
            if(value.length() == 10)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number is integer and its indian mobile number");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number is integer but not a indian mobile number");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter value is not a number");
        }
    }

}
```

**Error as Below**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "9867233256"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   InterviewPrograms.CheckMobileNumber.main(CheckMobileNumber.java:29)

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Hint: what is `int` range?

Comment: Ya. i got my mistake. Thanks @Pshemo
I edited my code to long instead of int.

Comment: Should use regex for that anyways.

Comment: @MuratK. I will write code in regex later but thanks for idea.

Comment: Your exception doesn't match your code. The stacktrace skipped your `Utility` class.

Comment: ya thanks. I corrected my code. @4castle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `long` instead of `int`:

```
 Long.parseLong(input);
```

`int` is giving error because its range is `2,147,483,647(inclusive)` only.